# Rooting Samsung Galaxy S6 without voiding warranty?

Tags: rooting, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Is there a way to root a Samsung Galaxy S6 without voiding the warranty, while also allowing it to OTA update to the latest version of Android supported by the device?

Using a PC to help in the process is fine, if needed.

Comment: Rooting always voids the warranty!

Comment: Most if not all rooting methods trip Knox.